# Passing dynamically Data Object in the data using AutoSuggest jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete, autosuggest

[AutoSuggest jQuery Plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin) requires an already available Data Object in order to run.
I need to use the user's selection from the first input as data in the second input.

The following snippet throws an error in firebug

> availableTeachers is not defined

```
var labs = {lesson:
                [
                    {
                        name: "FOO LESSON",
                        professors: [
                            { lab: "FOO TEACHER [Monday 3 pm]" },
                            { lab: "FOO TEACHER [Thursday 7 pm]" }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        name: "FOO LESSON",
                        professors: [
                            { lab: "FOO TEACHER [Tuesday 10 am]" }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
        };

firstStep.find("form input[type=text]").autoSuggest(labs.lesson, {
    selectedItemProp: "name",
    searchObjProps: "name",
    selectionLimit: 1,
    resultClick: function(data){
        availableTeachers = data.attributes;
    },
});

secondStep.find("form input[type=text]").autoSuggest(availableTeachers.professors, {
    selectedItemProp: "lab",
    searchObjProps: "lab",
    selectionLimit: 1,
});
```

**EDIT**

More testing, i predifined `availableTeachers` with some dummy data and i populate it with real data after the user selects a `lesson.name` in the first input.

> Second input keeps seeing only the dummy data

So far, it seems that autoSuggest plugin can only use static Data Objects or JSON requests.

Answer (score 0):

Where *is* availableTeachers defined? You should have some place where the variable is created. It is not enough to only assign it a value inside the lambda function, since the scope of *that* variable is local, unless it's created in the global scope.

Comment: It is created in the global scope because i didn't put "var" before the variable's name.

Comment: Do you understand what i am trying to say?